# Chrome extension development trying to make font bold

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am a programming beginner.
I would like to develop a simple Chrome extension that allows to **bold** for dragged content, when I click the icon.

Here is my code:

*1. manifest.json*

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "test",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "description": "test",

 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["<all_urls>"],
    "js":         ["content.js"]
 }],

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },

 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
 },

"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
 ]
}
```

*2. background.js*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);
function buttonClicked(tab) {
  let msg = {
    txt: "hello"
  }
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
}
```

*3. content.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.txt === "hello") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    alert(selection);
    boldText(selection);
  }
}

function boldText(selection) {
  alert(selection);
  selection = selection.toString().bold();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Are you having a particular problem with a certain part of this code? If so, please tell us the line number and the problem you are having. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the text bold modern browsers implements `execCommand` function that allows to bold, underline etc. on text.

You just have to make all body contentEditable then run exectCommand, like this:

```
function boldText() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("contentEditable", "");
  document.execCommand("bold");
}
```

I recommend you to always test directly in the console your DOM manipulation (what you do in content.js). (in Chrome hit F12 and then paste the code)
More information in [Make selected text bold/unbold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880271/make-selected-text-bold-unbold)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks! I will try this:) Also, can html tag be used with contentEditable for whole webpage, like <html contentEditable = "true">? If it is possible,modifying the webpage could be easily done with just once declaration of contentEditable, I think.

Comment: In addition, here is another question. "ContentEditable" attribute may also delete webpage content.I just want to make it bold or italic. Is there anything other than document.execCommand?

Comment: I answer this question by myself. If I turn designMode on and off before and after executing the function, the desired document.execCommand can be executed without affecting the remaining contents. Yeah! Thanks for your time, again:)

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea. I'm glad the answer helped you. Can you vote up and mark accepted this answer, you'll be very helpful, thanks!