# get the span tag name of selected text javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rangy

How to get the span name of selected text:

```
 <Span class='class1'> text2 text3 text4 text5 </span> text6
```

when user select text4 then I want to get Span=Class1

Any answer can help ( in Jquery or Rangy or ...)

Comment: try using onselect event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp

Answer (score 3):

This is a function which may help:

```
function getSelectionParentElement() {
    var parentEl = null, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            parentEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
            if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
                parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        parentEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    return parentEl;
}
```

It was taken from here [Get parent element of a selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215479/get-parent-element-of-a-selected-text), Author: Tim Down

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span').on('click', function(){
var classes = $(this).attr('class');
console.log(classes)   //if there are more than one class do classes.split(' ')
})
```

Extremely unedited fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tvp0q761/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS way of doing it. It assumes you'll have more than one span, hence `querySelectorAll` rather than `querySelector`.

**HTML**

```
<span class="class1"><p>text2</p><p>text3</p><p>text4</p></span>
<span class="class2"><p>text2</p><p>text3</p><p>text4</p></span>
<span class="class3"><p>text2</p><p>text3</p><p>text4</p></span>
```

**JS**

```
var spans = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span')).forEach(function (el) {
    el.onclick = showParentInfo;
});

function showParentInfo() {
    console.log(this.nodeName + '=' + this.className)   
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eovtrp8z/8/)

Comment: it works well but I am using a button to print with alert the class of selected word with rangy. How should I proceed

Comment: I don't know anything about rangy, I'm afraid. I did change my code so that it will alert the class of the text when you doubleclick on it (select it). [Does this help?](http://jsfiddle.net/eovtrp8z/14/)