# Surround 2 sibling elements with a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have this HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="foo">Some text</span>
    <span class="foo">FROM HERE</span>
    <span class="foo">some text</span>
    <span class="foo">TO HERE</span>
    <span class="foo">some text</span>
</div>
```

Now I'll already have the target elements as `$(start)` and `$(end)`. I want to make this html on a say a mouseup

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="foo">Some text</span>
    <span class="highlight">
        <span class="foo">FROM HERE</span>
        <span class="foo">some text</span>
        <span class="foo">TO HERE</span>
    </span>
    <span class="foo">some text</span>
</div>
```

and this I want to revert back.

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515175/get-parent-element-of-beginning-and-end-of-selected-text/32515300) where I already have the 'target elements'.

If it makes it easier, the structure will likely be always as above. A collection of `spans` within a `div`. I feel that jQuery [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) may be the best approach but I can't quite work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a collection of elements in jQuery, by using [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) and [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

[Fiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/yxn22f3p/4/)

Adding highlight:

```
var $wrapped = highlight($start, $end, '.foo'); // highlight and get the highlighted items collection
```

Removing highlight:

```
$wrapped.unwrap(); // use unwrap on the collection to remove highlight
```

Highlight func:

```
function highlight($start, $end) {
    /** return the wrapped collection **/
    return $start
        .nextUntil($end) // get elements between $start and $end
        .addBack() // add $start back
        .add($end) // add $end
        .wrapAll("<span class='highlight' />"); // wrap them with highlight
}
```